# What is the difference between parsing and Part Of Speech Tagging?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

I know that POS tagging labels each and every word in a sentence with its appropriate Part Of Speech , But isn't that what a Parser does too ? i.e, break a sentence into its component parts? 
I've looked this up on the internet but couldn't find any satisfactory explanation . 
Please clear my doubt.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two distinct procedures:

- POS Tagging: each *token* gets assigned a label which reflects its word class.
- Parsing: each *sentence* gets assigned a structure (often a tree) which reflects how its components are related to each other.

POS Tagging takes a tokenised sequence of words, and returns a list of annotated tokens, where each token has a word class label. This is often disambiguated by looking at the context surrounding the token.

There is also [*chunking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_parsing), which groups tokens into related groups (such as noun phrases). Chunks are non-overlapping sequences.

Parsing commonly results in a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) for a sentence; often there can be many possible trees in case of ambiguous sentences.

POS tagging is usually a preparatory step in parsing, as a parser typically operates on word classes (though there are some parsing algorithms that work with tokens directly, or a mixture of tags and tokens).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Cleared my doubt :)